# phonegap: Camera problems with iOS after 1. photo

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm doing a phonegap app for Andriod and iOS using the camera.
On Android all works fine! I can open the camera, take a pictue, save the picture into localstorage...
On iOS I can do the same but only once. If I want to do it again the camera will not open.
For Android I use phonegap 1.0(!), for iOS cordova 2.2.
Both Apps have the same javascript code.

`function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(savePicture, noPicture, { quality: 30, 
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL }); 
}`

It doesn't matter if I took a pictue or cancelled the camera process...

What can I do to use the camera more than once!
Please give me a short feedback.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

it was no problem of phonegap. It was a problem JQTouch but only on iOS!?
The problem was solved...

Thanks.